# XCode5 bot fails with SVN of sourcerepo.com : error validating server certificate

Tags: xcode, macos, ssl, svn, xcode5

I use sourcerepo.com as SVN server. My XCode5 bot complains : error validating server certificate for "https://myproject.sourcerepo.com:443"
- the certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the fingerprint etc....

How can I make my XCode Server accept this svn server and retrieve sources ?

thanks for your advice
Frank

Comment: Anybody suggestions ?

Answer (score 6):

1. Verify why the certificate is untrusted. (E.g., is it a self-signed certificate?)
2. Start Terminal and run `svn info https://myproject.sourcerepo.com:443/<path-to-repository>`. Accept the certificate permanently when prompted.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. XCode server keeps complaining 'Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://myproject.sourcerepo.com)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to make it work from the Xcode 5 release notes:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/developertools/rn-xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html

> Communicating with a remote SVN repository over HTTPS can fail with an
>   error similar to “Error validating server certificate for server
>   name.” Edit the file
>
> `/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist`
>
> and change the `TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates` key from false to true.
>
> Then, from a Terminal window, run:
>
> `sudo killall xcsbuildd`

I did exactly the above. To edit the file you actually need to

`sudo vi /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist`

After restarting the build daemon I was able to get my Xcode bot to checkout the sources from the remote repository and perform the integration. Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed this plist too cause this solution is also reported in de XCode server build logs. But I had the feeling that (1) the security of my XCode server is less reliable now and (2) fetching the sources from the SVN server has slowed down dramatically. It takes about 25 mins to fetch the code. Do you share the same experiences ?

Comment: @FrankVV I haven't experienced that long a delay to fetch the sources (mine takes a few minutes, for about 1000 files in my project)... As for security, it's really more complicated than to just conclude that the integration server is less secure, only based on this config change. In reality, I would say your source repository server is *already* the one less "secure" because it's using a SSL certificate signed by an unknown certificate authority... However, if the 2 servers are both on the same private network, you shouldn't lose too much sleep over this IMHO.